# stty in .profile causes: "stty: 'standard input': Inappropriat ioctl for device

Tags: .profile, stty

I added into my .profile file the command `stty werase ^H` (The command makes it possible that i can delete a word with Ctrl + Return).

But whenever i start my PC it prints the following error:

> Error found when loading /home/stefan/.profile:
>
> stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device
>
> As a result the session will not be configured correctly.
>   You should fix the problem as soon as feasible.

I tried to find the error with `strace -f -o <path-to-error> stty werase ^H`.
I have no idea tho what it does cause. [Link](https://pastebin.com/XnzSHxDL) for those who want to read it (pastebin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`stty`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/stty.html) acts on a device which is its stdin:

> Although no input is read from standard input, standard input shall be used to get the current terminal I/O characteristics and to set new terminal I/O characteristics.

The error you got means stdin is not a terminal. Using a terminal you can still reproduce the error by redirecting stdin:

```
</dev/null stty werase ^H
```

`.profile` is meant to be executed as [one-time setup](https://serverfault.com/a/261807) (e.g. by a login shell). In your case the file is apparently parsed by something not connected to a terminal. But even if `stty` in `.profile` succeeded, it wouldn't affect all possible terminals you could use *later*.

You need to run `stty` in each interactive shell separately. For Bash a good place is `.bashrc` (other shells use other files). It's a fairly common practice that `.profile` detects Bash and sources `.bashrc`. In some (rare, rather pathological) cases `.bashrc` may be sourced in a non-interactive shell, so you may want to [test if the shell is interactive](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26676/108618) just in case:

```
# in .bashrc
[[ $- == *i* ]] && stty werase ^H
```

Or better explicitly check if stdin is a terminal:

```
# portable approach
[ -t 0 ] && stty werase ^H
```

Or just silently ignore an error (if any) from `stty`:

```
# portable approach
stty werase ^H 2>/dev/null
```

Whatever you choose, the main point is `.profile` is not a good place for this.

Comment: thanks. didn't realize i could just iniate any command in .bashrc.